# PostgreSQL : Weighted ordering, order by columnA * 0.7 + columnB * 0.3?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given two selected numerical values. I can order on one. However, I wish to order on both based on a weighted formula. Is that possible?

For instance:

```
order by columnA * 0.7 + columnB * 0.3
```

What is the proper / easiest way to perform such queries?

Comment: The syntax looks correct. What is the error you got?

Comment: You could always weigh them in your SELECT with an extra field and then order on that alias. Would be much cleaner

Comment: @Trent, that presupposes he wants the value in the select...  if he wants to order it by this value but not necessarily show it as a field, the way he has done it would be perfect

Comment: @Hambone, in my experience - anyone trying to calculate in the ORDER is generally writing the query from scratch and just hadn't thought about expressing it in the SELECT. Another advantage to adding the return to the SELECT is you can debug the result set if the order doesn't look right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be inclined to do this:

```
SELECT
  columnA,
  columnB,
  (columnA * 0.7) + (columnB * 0.3) as weighted_value
FROM
  table
ORDER BY 
  weighted_value DESC
```

Firstly, it's much cleaner and easier to read. It also puts the expression where it belongs, in the select.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily, and your syntax is already correct.

Just put it this way, like

```
select *
from someTable
order by columnA * 0.7 + columnB * 0.3
```